# Can I tag a node in a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Did see any examples of how to do this, it looks like you can only tag a node with knife or the GUI is this true?

I want to tag a node in a recipe so when that recipe is applied to a node the node is tagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tag a node using the `tag` method inside your recipe.

Example:

```
tag('some_tag')
```

You can also access and edit the tags through the `node` object directly.

Comment: This is correct but for the sake of future-you I will say we would like to deprecate this some day (this == nodes writing to their own proscriptive data).